# How to insert data to mysql from html select, based on option selected

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a html form with select. Based on select option i want to display a sub form with different values and insert this data to database. I figured out how to display a sub form, but i don't know how to insert different values into database. Let's say i have an option CD with value size, a BOOK with value weight and FURNITURE with three values - width, length and height. With CD and BOOK it is simple, but how do i handle furniture with three parameters?

```
<form class="form-group" action="" method="post">
        <label for="id">SKU</label>
        <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control">
        <label for="type-switch">Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="type-switch" id="type" onchange="changeOptions(this)">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="form_1">DVD</option>
            <option value="form_2">Book</option>
            <option value="form_3">Furniture</option>
        </select>
    </form>
                        <!-- Sub Form-->
        <form class="sub-form" name="form_1">
            <label for="size">Size(MB)</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="size" id="">
        </form>
        <form class="sub-form" name="form_2">
            <label for="weight">Weight(KG)</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="weight" id="">
        </form>
        <form class="sub-form" name="form_3">
            <label for="height">Height(CM)</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="height" id="">
            <label for="width">Width*(CM)</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="width" id="">
            <label for="length">Length(CM)</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="length" id="">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You could simply use different table for storing different models and I think it would be best. Or you could format the data to a JSON and save it to a single table with these columns: `id`, `name`, `value`. For example: `name` would be "CD" and `value`: {size: 30}, or  FURNITURE and {width: 10, length:20, height: 30}. Then it doesn't matter how many parameters you have, because JSON is just a string, but it becomes a hassle to handle this kind of models, as they require json_decode to view their information.

Comment: Don't go the JSON way. It just complicates searching and displaying. Make a different table for each entity.